# Does bad electrical grounding mess up a laptop?

Tags: laptop, macbook, battery

I recently purchased a Macbook Pro retina display. When I use the 2 pin charger, and I touch the surface of the laptop I can feel electricity passing - basically laptop is vibrating softly. When I charge it with 3 pin, it does not vibrate. I have been charging it with 2 pin for about 10 days when I was not aware of this issue, so would that have messed up my laptop by any chance? To me laptop works perfectly, but I was wondering some hardware internally got messed up.

Comment: Did you mean "bad [electrical grounding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ground_%28electricity%29)" rather than "earthing" in your title? If so, click the "edit" link to correct your title so you may get better responses.

Comment: BTW, earthing is the generic British English term, grounding is US English. They're equivalent.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Some people are much more sensitive to this than others I've noticed over the years.

You will be happy to note that all modern electronics are designed to cope with non-earthed mains connections as they are not standard in some countries. (To be totally accurate, it isn't that the mains isn't earthed but that the mains circuit doesn't have a separate earth).

It is not uncommon to be able to feel what you describe on non-earthed equipment such as lamps and clocks and it shouldn't be a problem.

Of course, manufacturers will tell you that you *must* only use their chargers. They have a point but as long as you are using reputable makes that have been tested for your country, you should be fine.

Comment: Both the chargers we from Apple. They came with the laptop. I still can return the laptop, but not sure if it's worth it. Would there be a chance that some hardware got messed up with this? If so I will return the laptop.

Comment: @Anusha. In my experience, If hardware was messed up, you'd know. Seeing as how you don't mention or experience any symptoms/issues I'm going to go ahead and say you're overly cautious.

Comment: The way hardware gets messed up from this kind of potential, is when your person paths in high voltages at enough current to a curcuit of the laptop that cannot handle that.  The human being an electrical path.  Like touching any of the video , usb , thunderbird or mouse ports, headphone and mic, or passing tiny sparks through thin plastics like say a touchpad.  Chances are low that you have done that, and all you would have to do is test everything.    That only leaves Assuming :-) that you damaged something when you have normal software caused problems or other problems unrelated.

Comment: Generally, all electrical and electronic equipment made for consumer and business markets **has** to be resilient to this so that it is almost impossible to end up with a live electrical "circuit" on the outside of the device. Having a separate earth facilitates that, especially for high-power devices (vacuum cleaners, ovens, etc).

Answer (score 0):

This is so commonly misunderstood that I shall attempt to provide a short précis, then link to a good explanation which is not overly-technical.

**Common misconception - earthing/grounding**

Most small household appliances are not, in fact, earthed at all - even if there is a valid earth pin on the mains plug.
They are what is known as **'double insulated'** & carry this logo

[image]

The 'transformers' on this type of equipment are not the same as in high-power equipment & don't use a step-down coil transformer, linear supply. Instead they use a switch-mode supply.
All PSUs, whether linear or switch-mode leak a small amount of current due to capacitance. In double-insulated devices there is no true ground/earth so the design is optimised to try to prevent this leakage.
Unfortunately, switch-mode supplies run at very high frequencies, so the smaller capacitance in the smaller transformer ends up leaking just as much as the larger capacitance in a larger transformer running at 50 or at 60Hz for example.

The leakage current is usually less than 1mA and is often as low as 10uA, but even at such low current, it can still be present and still can cause problems.

So - the tingle or buzz that you feel is in fact **you** becoming the temporary ground/earth for this circuit.
It is usually safe, & any reputable manufacturer will ensure their PSUs are well within tolerance.

Cheap copies are cheap because they don't bother with most of the safety circuitry… you know, the stuff that makes the expensive one expensive in the first place ;-)

Have look at http://www.unitechelectronics.com/sparks.htm for a much more detailed explanation. Though it is aimed at hi-fi users & deals in 240v mains, the basic principles are identical.