# Graphics Card Unpowered Shorting

Tags: graphics-card, vga

The computer is all working fine but...

When ONLY the VGA cable is plugged into the PCI-E GFx card, I can detect a very minor shorting to the case. By detect, I mean a very feint tingling sensation on fingertips, which disappears and reappears when unplugging/replugging the VGA cable into the GFx card.
Note that by only the VGA cable, I mean there's no power cable or USB or anything else connected.

This behaviour persisted when trying with a completely separate monitor & VGA cable. In both cases the monitor was connected to power, but was switched off (soft-switch)

Has anyone else encountered behaviour such as this before, is it normal to have a very minor shorting of the VGA signal to the case??

Edit: Computer is ungrounded.

Comment: I assume trying a different card isn't possible?

Comment: It sounds like there's something wrong with the power setup. Maybe the monitor and computer are plugged into different circuits with a significant ground differential? Maybe the circuit is ungrounded or improperly grounded?

Comment: I've not noticed the effect previously with my other computer, but it seems to be more noticeable on the aluminium side panels of my case, rather than when touching the steelwork of the case itself.
The computer isn't plugged into the power at all; the only cable plugged into the computer is the VGA cable. The power must be going into the monitor then down the VGA cable, even with the monitor in the off state.

Comment: Is the computer grounded?

Comment: Update your question to point out, this happens on multiple computers, that indicates a building wiring problem.  UPS are good at getting rid of noisy power problems.

Comment: No computer isn't grounded; only cable connected is the VGA cable. (Case has rubber pads at the base)  I think I also felt the effect with the powersupply connected (i.e. when grounded), but I'll confirm tonight.

Comment: The power supply is a 600W Seasonic (so not a budget one), no other problems with it. Regardless, the power supply is not connected to any power cables.

Comment: It's hard to guess exactly what the issue is, but it's most likely a building wiring issue. Perhaps the monitor is connected to a ground line that's actually ungrounded and is being pulled up by devices connected to it.

Comment: All these tests have been with the monitor connected to the mains? I'd guess at leakage through the monitor's PSU, being transmitted down the VGA cable. You could probably feel the same tingling on the monitor itself, if you could find an exposed bit of chassis somewhere. Google "why does my laptop tingle" for a million (usually incorrect) explanations of how it happens - or see http://superuser.com/a/932411/347380 for a precis.

Comment: I switched GFx cards between my 2 rigs and now can't detect the tingling sensation on either. I suspect it's caused by leakage at the monitor as per Tetsujin's comment, which leaks into the ground cables in the VGA card, which are then earthed to the case in the computer. I presume not much to worry about, just a curiosity! Thanks all.