# Getting electricuted when touching the laptop

Tags: laptop, power-supply, battery, power, hp-pavilion

My friend bought [HP Pavilion 15-cc183cl](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B079ZYL7CW), the seller immediately removed the ground pin, because the circuits in my country don't have ground, (the circuits aren't designed to have a ground pin), and because it's hard to find somewhere to plug it, [the ground pin is so long](https://www.google.com/search?q=HP%2015-cc183cl%20charger&client=ubuntu&channel=fs&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiDwNKftb7fAhXhRxUIHTQ9C0wQ_AUIDigB&biw=1472&bih=735#imgrc=S7WJd4nIwViLUM:). My friend didn't test the laptop before removing the ground pin, so we don't know if it's causing the problem or not.

The laptop is made out of metal, when my friend places it on his metal desk, and plug it in, if the battery gets fully charged and he touch it, he gets electrocuted, especially on the corner of the laptop.

Is the problem caused because of removing the ground pin? If so could that be fixed?

Comment: Yes;  This problem is due to the modifications to the cable.  A surge protector might help, but honestly, the device was designed to function with a ground connected.

Comment: @Ramhound If he buys an original charger and manage to plug it, would it help or no? I mean if it gets plugged but if the country doesn't support grounding, does it mean he has to replace the laptop?

Comment: As I said a surge protector might help, as those do have ground plugs, I would try that before replacing the laptop.  In the future, I would not modify cables.

Comment: @Ramhound Okay sir, if you post an answer, I'll accept it so we could close the question

Comment: Are you sure they're getting electrocuted, as in main building AC power is shocking them continuously? That sounds potentially lethal. Or could it be a static discharge?

Comment: Surge-protect will do nothing at all, it's not surging so there's nothing to protect. Grounding the PSU *might* help, but this is most probably a switch-mode supply leak. See https://superuser.com/a/932411/347380 Semantically, being "electrocuted" implies enough power to throw you across the room, so either the question needs re-wording to give a more accurate description, or you need to get an electrician in to fully test the house circuits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Page 30 of the [Maintenance and Service Guide](http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c05493762) lists power adapter cords which plug into the power brick and are designed for many nations. However, Lebanon is not listed, so please look at [these pictures of power plugs and sockets](https://www.power-plugs-sockets.com/us/lebanon/) for Lebanon, and then acquire the appropriate wall cord.  Until then, get a rubber sheet, cover the laptop, and use a USB attached keyboard.